# Why does this CURL work in PHP but not in the shell

Tags: php, linux, shell, curl

I'm trying to access an API. I can do this from PHP

```
<?php

$url = 'http://apiurl/path';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('API-KEY: myKey'));
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$curlInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output; /*success!*/
```

However, doing this from the command line triggers a 403 error.

```
curl -i -v -H "API-KEY: myKey" http://apiurl/path
/*failure!*/
```

What is PHP doing differently? Or have I got a syntax error in my command line code?

Comment: Are you running these on the same server? Does the API server examine the User-Agent header? Have you tried comparing the requests using something like a logging proxy server? (Like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com), say, or [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/)?)

Comment: As far as I can see, you're doing the right thing—but the command-line Curl will probably send User-Agent, whereas my php installation doesn't. That's about the only difference. Try adding `-H "User-Agent:` to remove the user agent to see if it makes a difference. (Could there possibly be some character in your API key that's being interpreted differently on the command line?)

Comment: @mattgibson yes, same server. Can I disable the user agent on the command line? so that they are exactly the same.

Comment: Yes; add `-H "User-Agent:"` —similar to what you're doing with "API-KEY", but if you provide no value it should remove the header.

Comment: @MattGibson Sorry, I did not see that you had already provided the user agent reset. Can you please submit that as an answer so I can accept? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that worked, then? Will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only obvious difference I can see is that command-line PHP adds a User-Agent header by default. Possibly the API server you're using rejects requests from the Curl user agent? Try removing it from the command-line by adding the parameter `-H "User-Agent:"`